# Fpdf and PDF_LABEL

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to set up a labeling printing system in PHP and on each label I would like to add a logo on top of it and I can't manage to work it, because on fpdf images are treated as a cell it doesn't work

EDIT:

The code is as follows:

```
 for($i=1;$i<=$nolabels;$i++) {
$text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s%s%s", "", "","","", "$destination", "$label", "USE BY: $date", "$i", '/', "$nolabels");
$pdf->Add_Label($text);}

for($i=1;$i<=$nolabels2;$i++) {
$text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s%s%s", "$destination", "$label2", "USE BY: $date", "$i", '/', "$nolabels2");
$pdf->Add_Label($text);
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've written ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make additional "addHeader" and call it on each page. Here is one example with using X and Y coordinates

```
public function addHeader($pdf, $addPageNum)
  {
    // Header
    if ($addPageNum) {
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
      $pdf->SetTextColor(168, 168, 168);
      $pdf->SetXY(20, 265);
      $pdf->Cell(0, 5, __('Page') . ' ' . $pdf->PageNo() . ' von ' . '{nb}', 0, 1, 'C', 0);
    }
    // Footer photo
    $pdf->Image(ROOT . '/webroot/img/companyLogo.png', 0, 270, 210);
  }
```

Comment: I have tried that however this only puts an image on the top of the page and I need it inside each label which has 6 per page

Comment: @André Gomes To set exact position use -> $pdf->Image(ROOT . '/webroot/img/companyLogo.png', 0, 270, 210); and more info you can find http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm those parameters are flot X Y Z

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing shows up. Sorry guys but I have been weeks over this and nothing seems to work